# Visual Studio (SSDT) 2017 unable to start SSIS package if SSAS project in solution

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I using SSDT 2017 and i can't start SSIS packages if solution contains cube project.
After press Start button new window opens and nothing happens.

1. My solution with SSAS and SSIS projects

[image: solution]

2. Open a package and press Start to debug

[image: only SSIS package open]

3. Instead run package a window popup with cube design

[image: cube and package windows]

If solution contains only SSIS project works well.

Comment: you can try to install ssdt using offline installer

Comment: that's how it was done

Comment: Update: i migrated to sql 2019 with visual studio 2019 and the bug still happens, but i found that it only happens if i open the model.bin before trying to run a package.